# How to give permission to a Shiny-App to upload/download data from ONLY ONE specific Dropbox folder?

Tags: shiny, dropbox

I want my Dropbox account to be used for remote storage by my shiny app.

What I understand is that, the authentication file ".httr-oauth" generated by using "rdrop2", to serve this purpose, opens up the whole of my dropbox to the shiny-app. However, I would like to limit this permission with a SINGLE predetermined dropbox folder.

If I got it right up to this point, how can I do that?

Comment: Have you considered creating a secondary Dropbox account just for your app and sharing the folder with that account?

Comment: thanks @Frank Schmitt, I am aware of your solution but I was wondering whether I could do that within a single account. The below answer sorts out my problem. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restrict the access of a specific dropbox folder inside the app through conditions like

```
if(folder_name == authorised_folder) {let in and process} else {display unauthorised warning message}
```

or at the file level

```
if (file %in% authorised_folder) {let in} else {unauthorised}
```

or you can use other things like

```
assertthat::assert_that(folder %in% authorised folder)
```